# Is the JavaScript RegExp implicit method deprecated?

Tags: javascript, regex

So everyone knows what I mean by "implicit methods"?  They're like those default properties
from the Windows COM days of yore, where you could type something like

```
val = obj(arguments)
```

and it would be interpreted as

```
val = obj.defaultMethod(arguments)
```

I just found out JavaScript has the same thing: the default method of a RegExp object
appears to be 'exec', as in

```
/(\w{4})/('yip jump man')[1]
==> jump
```

This even works when the RegExp object is assigned to a variable, and even when
it's created with the RegExp constructor, instead of `/.../`, which is good news
to us fans of referential transparency.

Where is this documented, and/or is it deprecated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature is *non-standard*, some implementations like the Mozilla (Spidermonkey and Rhino) and the Google Chrome (V8) include it, but I would *highly discourage* its usage, because it isn't part of the specification.

Those implementations make `RegExp` objects *callable*, and invoking those objects is equivalent to call the `.exec` method.

In Chrome (and Firefox 2.x) even when you use the `typeof` operator with a `RegExp` object, you get `"function"` (because they implement the [`[[Call]]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) internal method).

```
typeof /foo/ == "function"; // true
```

Also IMO I don't see the benefit of using:

```
regexp(str);
```

Versus:

```
regexp.exec(str);
```

This is slightly documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) by Mozilla.

Comment: Right to the point on both counts.  Thanks.  I didn't like it either, but was looking for ammo to defend my point. Since one rarely types JS code interactively, there isn't much benefit to the short form.

Comment: @Eric Somebody is finding it difficult to understand your comment, and has asked a question on [ELU.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/392480/50044). It'd be great if you could drop by.

Comment: @NVZ, you are so friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all functions are objects, so you can do this:

```
var obj = function () {
    alert('Doing my default!');
};
obj.prop1 = 'Hello world';
obj.prop2 = function () {
    alert('Other method');
};

obj(); // 'Doing my default!'
alert(obj.prop1); // 'Hello world'
obj.prop2(); // 'Other method'
```